# time and date from nvachar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Want to convert NVarchar to Time and date using update column command in sql server

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[timeconvert](
[sno] [int] NULL,
[Duration_Load] [nvarchar](7) NULL,
[Duration] [time](7) NULL,
[Estimated_Date_of_Arrival_Load] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[Estimated_Date_of_Arrival] [date] NULL )

INSERT [dbo].[timeconvert] VALUES  (1, N'03:26', NULL, N'29.01.2019', NULL) ,(2, N'02:45', NULL, N'30.01.2019', NULL),(3, NULL, NULL, N'03.02.2019', NULL),(4, N'10.25', NULL, N'11.02.2019', NULL)
```

I want to update the time table with time and date datatype accordingly in the next column.

```
update  dbo.timeconvert set Duration = time(Duration_Load) , Estimated_Date_of_Arrival = date(Estimated_Date_of_Arrival)
```

Expected result should match the format in the column type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE dbo.timeconvert
SET Duration = REPLACE(Duration_Load,'.',':'),
    Estimated_Date_of_Arrival  = SUBSTRING(Estimated_Date_of_Arrival_Load,4,2)+'/'+LEFT(Estimated_Date_of_Arrival_Load,2)+'/'+RIGHT(Estimated_Date_of_Arrival_Load,4)
```

Comment: You can Try this....SELECT 
 [sno],
 [Duration_Load],
 LEFT([Duration],5) AS [Duration],
 [Estimated_Date_of_Arrival_Load],
 [Estimated_Date_of_Arrival]
FROM 
 DBO.[timeconvert]

Answer (score 1):

use cast() and convert() function

```
update  dbo.timeconvert set Duration = CONVERT( TIME, Duration_Load ), Estimated_Date_of_Arrival 
= cast(Estimated_Date_of_Arrival as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
UPDATE dbo.timeconvert 
SET Duration = CONVERT( TIME, Duration_Load ), Estimated_Date_of_Arrival = CONVERT(DATE,Estimated_Date_of_Arrival_Load)
```

Comment: Getting below errorMsg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Please change datatype length [Estimated_Date_of_Arrival_Load] [nvarchar](10) to  [Estimated_Date_of_Arrival_Load] [nvarchar](100)

Comment: still i get the same errror